# Issue with multiple model co-ordinates mismatch forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have two models that should be perfectly aligned together but it is taking the same global offset from the first model and applying it to the second model which creates alignment issues.

Basically I want both of my models to place at there own co-ordinates.

even if i provide globalOffset: {x:0,y:0,z:0}, its shattering.

My code :

```
 Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
          
            const div = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(div);
            viewer.start();
            urn.map((m)=>{
                Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(`urn:${m.urn}`, (doc) => {
                    var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
                
                    var modelOption = {
                                keepCurrentModels: true,
                                applyScaling: 'm'
                    };
                  
                    onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc,modelOption);
                });

            })
            
        });
      
      
    }
    

    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc,opt) {
      var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
      viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, opt).then(i => {
          viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, function () {
              
               // extra code 
                
            });
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check my sample here ([MultipleModelUtil](https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil/blob/master/MultipleModelUtil.js#L147)), and go to [line#147](https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil/blob/master/MultipleModelUtil.js#L147)
to apply **globalOffset** to the second model. Or check AggrefatedView here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7

**Note. Please don't set the globalOffset to `{x:0, y:0, z:}`, you will encounter the [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) issue (e.g. model is flicking ... )**

Comment: It's giving me the error, it is taking localhost rather than taking autodesk host Xhr.js:750 GET http://localhost:8083/derivativeservice/

Comment: Which one? And where?

Comment: solved that error, but still, models are not aligning perfectly.

Comment: Please share details on the problem you met. It’s hard for me to understand the issue with serval lines of words.

Comment: To align Revit models, your models must co-origin. Please try to use link REVIT models of the Revit UI with either origin-to-origin or by shared coordinates to check if their relative position is correct

Comment: The models that I was talking about are still not aligning perfectly, actually, it should be on top of each other but they are shown very far from each other, I tried loading the models that were running perfectly before, and now those models are coming wrongly align. FYI I didn't provided globalOffset before.

Comment: Could you consider providing non-confidential reproducible models demonstrating this issue to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com to help understand the problem quickly?